# Apple Receipt Validation, IAP

Tags: ios, node.js, in-app-purchase

Folks,
  I am using https://github.com/pcrawfor/iap_verifier `verifyAutoRenewReceipt` method to check a receipt the phone sends me in Sandbox.

The response I get back, is a JSON object, with `status=0` constantly.  I cant seem to get the receipts to expire and get the `21006` back.

So what I think needs to be done, is parsing the `apple_receipt_info` array, and matching up the current date with expires date..  Super tedious task. Am I on the right track?

here is the `purchase_date` ahead of the `expires_date` ???

```
{
  "quantity" : "1",
  "product_id" : "Individual",
  "transaction_id" : "1000000125781694",
  "original_transaction_id" : "1000000125781334",
  "purchase_date" : "2014-10-01 19:31:49 Etc/GMT",
  "purchase_date_ms" : "1412191909545",
  "purchase_date_pst" : "2014-10-01 12:31:49 America/Los_Angeles",
  "original_purchase_date" : "2014-09-30 23:45:39 Etc/GMT",
  "original_purchase_date_ms" : "1412120739000",
  "original_purchase_date_pst" : "2014-09-30 16:45:39 America/Los_Angeles",
  "expires_date" : "2014-09-30 23:51:21 Etc/GMT",
  "expires_date_ms" : "1412121081000",
  "expires_date_pst" : "2014-09-30 16:51:21 America/Los_Angeles",
  "web_order_line_item_id" : "1000000028661959",
  "is_trial_period" : "false"
}
```

I couldnt get the `verifyReceipt` method to work, as I kept getting malformed data errors back from Apple.  Not sure what that function does...

Comment: Also, when using moment.js to convert the `expires_date_ms`, the year is ridiculously offset.  It seems that all the _ms timestamps are not useable.

Comment: Are you getting back the Grand Unified Receipt (iOS 7+) or the old iOS 6 style?

Comment: `expires_date_ms` is milliseconds since unix epoch and works just fine: 1412121081000  = Tue, 30 Sep 2014 23:51:21 GMT